# I've just go the "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." screen

Tags: recovery-mode

I broke my system by editing one of the gnome applications found in the applications directory, it was something to do with libreoffice writer I think. I changed the path of the icon to an image I made for it, and then my system broke. I did use time shift, but I have no clue how to recover using it. Can you give me some suggestions on how I can recover the system to the previous state, or atleast keep the existing files?

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Changing a LibreOffice file won't cause your problem... if that's what you changed. Run a `fsck` on your system disk.

Comment: 21.10, and it was an application inside the large applications directory (there are two) which had something similar to liner office in the file name. I know that's what caused it, because the system broke immediately after.

Comment: I ran the fsck and it hasn't fixed it.

Comment: Well, if you don't know what applications directory, and you don't remember the filename, and you don't know what you changed in the file, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: That's not enough detail either. Don't expect us to search for an "applications" directory, and guess what file you modified. Do your own homework, and if you can get more details, we'll be glad to help you.

Comment: It is not very easy to check these things when you don't have a computer. I will give more detail when I can.

Comment: An explanation on how to recover using time shift from the root shell prompt would also suffice, if you can do that.

Comment: Very brief instructions in my quickie answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot to **Recovery Mode** from the GRUB menu.

- Remount the system disk as r/w...

`sudo mount -o rw,remount /`

- To get help on timeshift...

`man timeshift`

- Or navigate to the directory/filename that you changed and undo the changes...

`cd /usr/share/applications`

`ls -alt | more` # to find the newest modified filename

`sudo pico libreoffice-math.desktop`

Comment: That should be enough to get me started, thank you. Not the right file I don't think but that's on me.

Comment: I found the file and fixed it. Still didn't start, but I was able to use man time shift to get it going again. Didn't need to remount.

Comment: @user1560499 Did the `ls -alt` command help you find the file? What was it's name? I'd like to look at it on my system. The remount would have been necessary to be able to edit the file and save changes. Timeshift --restore worked for you... that's great... I was right, your file edit didn't cause your boot problem. It was some other system-related problem.

Comment: the file was libreoffice-math.desktop and I just found it using ls and looking through the list. Yes, it would seem that it didn't cause the problem because changing the file back didn't fix it, however, I wouldn't say that is conclusive evidence (you would know better than me). I would say there is good reason to think it was editing that file that caused it, because I was restarting the gnome shell every minute or so prior to the system going down.

Comment: "The remount would have been necessary to be able to edit the file and save changes." Maybe that's the issue then. I just used sudo pico and then wrote out using ctrl+o. However, when I restarted and went back to check that it had actually modified the file, it had saved the change (atleast within the root shell prompt screen).

Comment: @user1560499 Well, I guess we'll never really know what broke your system, but at least timeshift was able to get you back running again.

Comment: I just determined the cause. I edited the icon in the gnome-control-center.desktop application. I changed it back to the original after it broke the system and booted fine after.

Comment: @user1560499 Thanks for the update!